# MYSQL - Retornar ocorrências mais próximo da REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

Preciso retornar o numero de ocorrências mais próximo da REGEXP, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nome_produto REGEXP 'vestido|longo|manga|curta'
```

A ideia é que esta query me retorne assim

1. Vestido longo com mangas curtas
2. Vestido perolado com mangas curtas
3. Vestido Longo líndissimo ..

Mas ele retorna algo como:

1. Vestido lindo para usar no verão
2. Vestido qualquercoisa..

Enfim, ele não ordenada pelo maior número de ocorrências, têm como fazer isso?
Isso é pra um sistema de busca simples que preciso fazer..

Answer (score 1):

Isto deverá ajudar a atingir aquilo que desejas.

```
SELECT * , MATCH (nome_produto) AGAINST ('vestido longo manga curta' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevancia 
FROM tabela
WHERE MATCH (nome_produto) AGAINST ('vestido longo manga curta' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevancia
```